# Flux architecture for a login or basically most forms processing

Tags: reactjs, reactjs-flux, flux

I am trying to understand a bit more about flux architecture and am designing a simple login component. Suppose when you login (POST ajax) and an error comes back. How would the information flow in flux?

1. I think the LoginComponent should do the work on a handleSubmit function.
2. After the ajax call comes back with an error and message should the component create an action such as "UpdateLoginStatus with payload {message: "no e-mail found"}. This would then trigger a LoginStore or something to save the status message and then it would emit an event such as "LoginStatusMessageChanged".
3. Another totally different component called LoginStatusMessage would register to listen to events on the LoginStore. It would get notified of this event and then proceede to update it's own state with the message. It would go out to LoginStore and fetch the message and display it to the user via render.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error Handler with Flux](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27957460/error-handler-with-flux)

Comment: Question title asks one thing, but the question body seems to ask "how to handle errors in Flux", which has been [answered in another question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27969524/538570).

Answer (score 0):

I believe this example covere your question quite well: https://github.com/przeor/react-router-flux-starter-kit/

Comment: Hi. This would be great if it was updated to use react-router 1.0.0 beta 3

Answer (score 0):

Don't let your Component do the request. That would be mixing UI with business logic. That is always bad.

---

Entered username, password and button should be handled by your React component. Whenever the button gets clicked, the component should trigger an action.

```
//Component.js

handleSubmit: function(){
    UserActions.login(this.state.username, this.state.password);
}
```

The action informs the store:

```
//UserActions.js

login(username, password) {
    this.dispatch({username: username, password: password});
}
```

The Store then executes the needed AJAX (as the actions never should cause changes or requests themselves).

Depending on success or error, your store then triggers a new action. It should never save the response directly. Never save data in stores without an preceding action. If you want to, you can save that you are currently logging in (For instance, if you want to animate a spinner)

```
//UserStore.js

handleLogin(credentials) {
    this.isLoggingIn = true;
    AuthService.login(credentials.username, credentials.password).then((user) => {
        UserActions.loginSuccess(user);
    }).catch((errorMessage) => {
        UserActions.loginFailed(errorMessage);
    })
}
```

The actions again do their dumb thing, as they always should be nothing but dumb messengers.

```
//UserActions.js

loginSuccess(user) {
    this.dispatch(user);
}

loginFailed(errorMessage) {
    this.dispatch(errorMessage);
}
```

Up next: handle the actions in your store!

```
//UserStore.js

handleLoginSuccess(user) {
    this.user = user;
    this.isLoggedIn = true;
    this.isLoggingIn = false;
}

handleLoginFailed(errorMessage) {
    this.errorMessage = errorMessage;
    this.isLoggingIn = false;
}
```

That's it. As long as your component listens to the UserStore, it get's informed when your user logs in, is successfully logged in or had an error, while having a clear separation of Logic and UI and a unimanual flow.

EDIT: Code examples are mostly pseudocodish. Actual implementation depend on your Flux framework.